# ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM" when setting default privileges

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I am trying to create a user, `test`, which only has `INSERT` privileges to a database, `test2`. This database is populated with tables with data inserted by the `postgres` user.

The user `test` should only be able to INSERT data into the database tables and nothing else. It should not be able to delete or alter any data currently in the database.

I attempted using the command
`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE test GRANT INSERT ON TABLES FROM "test2";`
but got an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: ...T PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE test GRANT INSERT ON TABLES FROM "test...
                                                             ^
```

I have also attempted using the GRANT command standalone but seem to be getting an error about relations not existing.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't the syntax like this: GRANT  INSERT ON mytable TO username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you mean `to`. The syntax here (from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)) is:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
    [ FOR { ROLE | USER } target_role [, ...] ]
    [ IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] ]
    abbreviated_grant_or_revoke

where abbreviated_grant_or_revoke is one of:

GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON TABLES
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

so

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE test GRANT INSERT ON TABLES TO "test2";
```